# Ionic send data when routing another page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I havea problem: I want to send data from my `home.html` page to `map.html` page. So I am trying to pass the data from `HomeController` to `MapController`. But I don't want to use `Service`..
I am looking for a solution sending data simply by using `$state.go` or anything else...

```
var myObject = {
    x: "asdsad",
    y: "skdfj",
    ....
}

$state.go('map', {"test":myObject})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've started totally right.

In your state, define the params expected, example:

```
.state('tab.compare-info', {
  url: '/compare/info',
  params: {
    map: null
  },
  template: '<p></p>',
  controller: 'Ctrl'
}
```

and call the route with

```
$state.go('tab.compare-info', {map: object});
```

Inside the destination state controller, inject $stateParam and get the parameter:

```
function Ctrl($stateParams) {
    var map = $stateParams.map;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :D